# Scapy bpf could not filter ethernet packet with mac address

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I have trouble filtering ethernet packets. Below is my setup:

I have a board sending Ethernet packets through an Ethernet link to a laptop running ubuntu os. The ethernet packet is very simple: Ethernet layer concat with Raw Data.

My wireshark was able to received and identified the Ethernet packet.
Now I am trying to filter out those which are not directed towards my laptop, and analyze them in a python program. I tried using the following

```
sniff(iface = 'eth0', prn = lambda x : x.show(), filter = 'ether host 00:11:22:33:44:55')
sniff(iface = 'eth0', prn = lambda x : x.show(), filter = 'ether dst 00:11:22:33:44:55')
```

But scapy wasn't able to display any incoming packet that I sent from the board. However, both wireshark and tcpdump were able to recognize and analyze the packet

```
tcpdump -A -i eth0 ether host 00:11:22:33:44:55  (this recognizes incoming packets)
```

I also tried replacing the board with a PC but the issue stays: I was able to receive it using wireshark and tcpdump, but scapy filter just ignores the packet and nothing was printed out.

Comment: are you able to sniff those packet with scapy without specyfing a filter?

Comment: Yes. If filter = '' then all packets are printed, but with filter as above then nothing is printed

Comment: will scapy sniff icmp packets (when you're pinging machine where scapy is sniffing) with filter on?

Comment: Everything is filtered out with the above filter. However, I was still able to use filters like "type mgt" or "subtype beacon"

Comment: I suspect that the tcpdump module that scapy uses is different from the one that i am using. Is there any way to check this?